# Displaying sequence numbers for the records in the DataTable and data binding is done through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
public List<string[]> NotificationManagementData(IEnumerable<NotificationManagements> ComplaintEntry, int currentUserId)
{
    return ComplaintEntry.Select((entry, index) => new string[]
    {      
        (index + 1).ToString(),                 
        GetLinks(currentUserId, entry),
        entry.state_Id,
        entry.refType,                
        entry.request,
        entry.action,
        Common.Encrypt(currentUserId.ToString(), entry.id.ToString())
    }).ToList();
}
```

For displaying sequence number for each record i am just adding 1 to index value for each entry.The above code is working fine if all records are in one page. But if there are more than 1 pages the sequence number again starts from 1 in second page. Please help me to get sequence number continued in the next pages aswell. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does paging come in to play? I don't see anything in your sample code that suggests you are paging data.

Comment: As @JasonBoyd pointed out, we need to get more info on how you implemented the pagination. In most cases you will need to manually calculate `[page number] * [rows per page] + index` and pass it in as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that pagination is done on `ComplaintEntry` level (there's no other level to do it, because of `ToList()` call) you need to pass the initial row number to the method, like this:

```
public List<string[]> NotificationManagementData(IEnumerable<NotificationManagements> ComplaintEntry, int currentUserId, int firstRow) {
    return ComplaintEntry.Select((entry, index) => new string[] { 
        (index + firstRow).ToString(),                 
        GetLinks(currentUserId, entry),
        entry.state_Id,
        entry.refType,                
        entry.request,
        entry.action,
        Common.Encrypt(currentUserId.ToString(), entry.id.ToString())
    }).ToList();
}
```

The caller of `NotificationManagementData` knows the current page, so they can do the math to figure out what to pass to the `firstRow` parameter.